# Wix custom installer shows two exe in task manager

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I am using a custom installer in Wix 3.10. In my custom bootstrapper contains three exe packages.
When i am accept the UAC it shows two exe in the task manager. Why it shows two exe in taskmanager?

Answer (score 1):

One process is the unelevated process that is showing the UI. The other one is the elevated process running your MSIs and other packages. Doing it this way means you only ever get one UAC popup during your install because all packages are run by the elevated process and inherit the elevated status when they run so they never need to do a UAC prompt.